# Detect if svn available on server (within PHP)

Tags: php, svn, detection

I run an open source PHP script, which is being used on all sorts of server environments. I need to detect within PHP whether or not the *svn* command is available on the server. The idea is that I'll use it as the primary way to download files for installation / upgrading components, and use older methods (manual download) as a secondary method.

I know I can call *svn export* through PHP with the exec() or system() commands, but what I'm really looking for is a command line function to test for SVN's presence, like:

exec("test svn");

which would (ideally) output a boolean or something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you could always parse the response from svn help, Example: $svn_output = \`svn help\`;

Comment: I was wondering about that. But what if the help was outputted in a different language? (presumably that's possible / common with unix / windows)

Comment: if this is a SVN server for which you're pulling code from I think you should know the region/language but if you don't you could always translate it using PHP http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php and http://www.phpriot.com/articles/google-translate-api

Comment: How about `which svn` to see if an svn binary exists in the system path?

Answer (score 1):

```
function hasSvn() {
  return shell_exec('which svn') != '';
}
```